# Set value of menu list option in to another select option

Tags: javascript, html

I want when selecting a value from the menu list, that value will be assigned to the select option.

My menu list like this:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Garden</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a id="center_1" value="tree_1">Tree 1</a></li>
         <li><a id="center_2" value="tree_2">Tree 2</a></li>
         <li><a id="center_3" value="tree_3">Tree 3</a></li>           
      </ul>
  </li>
  ......
</ul>
```

After selecting `Tree 1` its value will be assigned to this `select option`:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option id="output">'selected value'</option>
</select>
```

And if the selected value in option is `Tree 1` then the 2nd option will show its subvalues

Maybe like this (illustration):

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery too?

Comment: @PunitGajjar if jQuery can solve my problem I will use it too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var column1RelArray = [];

        $('#column1 li').each(function() {
           column1RelArray.push($(this).text());
        });



        $.each(column1RelArray, function( index, menuItem ) {


            var optionExists = ($('#columnsAvailable option[value='+menuItem+']').length > 0);

            if(!optionExists)
            {
                $('#columnsAvailable').append("<option value='"+menuItem+"'>"+menuItem+"</option>");
            }

        });


    });
```

```html
<li>
    <a href="#">Garden</a>
    <ul id="column1">
        <li>Tree 1</li>
        <li>Tree 2</li>
        <li>Tree 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<select class="form-control" id="columnsAvailable">
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

First of all, add some ID to your select box

```
<select class="form-control" id="columnsAvailable">
```

I assume you must be using jQuery too, so before appending your value to the select box you would like to check if the value exists or not.

Check the code below

```
var menuItem = "Tree1";

var optionExists = ($('#columnsAvailable option[value='+menuItem+']').length > 0);

if(!optionExists)
{
    $('#columnsAvailable').append("<option value='"+menuItem+"'>"+menuItem+"</option>");
}
```

With `var menuItem = "Tree1";` you can use your own value you would like to get if from the click event or anyhow you wish to

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But how can i assign value from menu list `Garden` to option select

Comment: @Jayzz , I have edited the code, if you can please check and let me know if you got the idea what I have did

Comment: I tried adding your code, but an error appeared: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #columnsAvailable option[value=Tree 1]`. I'm use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: As I said, First of all, add some ID to your select box

<select class="form-control" id="columnsAvailable">

Try to run snippet and compare your code  with mine, you will get better idea

Comment: I definitely added the ` <select class = "form-control" id = "columnAvailable">` and `id="column1"` as your suggestion. The error still appears

Comment: Typo `columnsAvailable` - plural

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily with vanila js . just add a onchange eventlistner on first select option that means when you are selecting something from first select then onchange event will be fired up and that results to appear the second select options . thats it !! this will definitely solve your problem.

```js
let select2=document.getElementById("select2")
let show=()=>{
    select2.style.visibility="visible"
}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="show()">
    <option id="center_1" class="center" value="tree_1">Tree 1</option>
    <option id="center_2" class="center" value="tree_2">Tree 2</option>
    <option id="center_3" class="center" value="tree_3">Tree 3</option>           
</select>
<select id="select2" style="visibility: hidden">
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you, this is one of the simplest way.